# Displaying data from a list in R without dynamically changing variable names

Tags: r

I'm writing some code in R that builds a list of data frames. While it runs, it needs to display each of the data frames it creates in a separate tab. The data frames and the list are both created by several nested for loops, along the lines of:

```
df.list <- vector("list", length(e))
i <- 1
for (...){
  data <- as.data.frame(stuff)
  j <- 1
  for (...){
    for (...){
      [loop stuff]
      data[j,] <- [more stuff]
    }
  }
  df.list[[i]] <- data
  i <- i + 1
}
```

The question is where to put the "View" function. If I add a second loop at the end that runs through the list and displays the data frames, then they all get named "df.list". If I put View(data) right before df.list[[i]] <- data then they all get named "data". Having them all have the same name is not an acceptable situation for this context. Ideally, I would be able to name them whatever string I want, but I would settle for anything that is reasonably understandable and distinguishable from the other data frames.

I know I can solve this by dynamically changing the variable name to be datai where i is the list index, but that's almost always the wrong way to do things.

Comment: Does `df.list` have "names"? Unless I'm missing something, you could use `for(nm in names(df.list)) View(df.list[[nm]], nm)` or, inside the loops, accessing/creating the `i` name and passing it to `View`.

Comment: No, you're totally right. Somehow I missed the fact that you can call View(data, name). I thought the View function wouldn't take a name argument. Write this as an answer and I'll accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Posting the solution from the comments so I can close:

The View() function takes names as optional arguments! `View(data, name)` will display `data` and call the tab `name`

Answer (score 2):

I thought I'd never post an answer using `eval(parse())`, but it's the only way I can think to make this work:

```
# sample data
df.list = list(mtcars, iris)
# name your list however you want the tabs to be named
names(df.list) = c("mtcars data", "this is iris")

for (i in seq_along(df.list)) eval(parse(text = sprintf("View(df.list[['%s']])", names(df.list)[i])))
```

This might be what you meant by "dynamically changing the variable name to be datai where i is the list index", and I agree that it's almost always wrong. In this case it may also be by far the most expedient way to do it as well.

Comment: This is roughly equivalent to what I had in mind, yes. It's kinda mind blowing to me that this is how you do it... I can't think of any other ways, expedient or not

Comment: I'm going to leave this open for a while in hopes that someone has a better idea.

Comment: I hope someone does!